How can I run (C++) unit tests without "spinning" the node?
[ros2 humble]
Edit 2 - More general form of the question, but previous question below the line
Generally speaking, when I run a unit test, I don't want to test that the ROS software works, I want to test that the code I've written works. So, to the extent possible, I would like to be able to test up to the edges where I hand the problem over to ROS mechanisms.
For example (the original question): my node contains a timer that executes a callback method periodically. I don't want to test that the timer itself works, I just want to test that A) it has the right period, and B) the correct behavior occurs on timeout. This is particularly true if timers have long time periods, it's costly to have a unit test wait that long.
As mentioned below in the solution I've found, I think there is a hacky way to at least address the problem for "pure inputs" to the node: timers and subscribers. I can inspect them via callback groups and poke them to operate.
I still would like to hunt down how I can test 'outputs' (publishers) and service/client interfaces as well without having to actually spin a node or invoke the general ROS mechanics. My current guess at a not particularly friendly solution would be to somehow swap out the publishers/services/clients with mock versions, perhaps by providing factory functions or some other injection method. But very curious if anyone knows a better approach.
Original question below:

IMO, it's bad practice for a unit test to take more than a millisecond or so to execute. Additionally, tests using 'wall clock' timers are a bit notoriously flaky depending on system usage.
Suppose I have a node that has a timer with a callback function. As a part of a unit test, I should be able to ensure that function is called when the timeout is triggered. I usually prefer to use dependency injection patterns that would allow me to inject alternate implementations of an interface for the sake of testing. But ROS really doesn't seem built to do that. So is there a way I can get access to the timer from the node itself? Is there some way I can force it to time out right away, rather than waiting for the 'real' length of time to pass? Can I inspect the timer in some way to make sure it was set to the anticipated duration, or maybe even get its callback directly and just run the callback myself to bypass the ROS library logic (which is already sufficiently unit tested for my purposes).
I guess I am assuming that since the code uses a 'WallTimer', I can't use the use_sim_time mechanisms to force a similar timeout.

Edit: to write down where I currently am in researching this topic:
Going through the source code of rclcpp: I see that Node::create_wall_timer(...) adds a wall timer to the callback group of the node. I suspect / hope that I might be able to get the callback group of a node, dig into the timers table, extract my timer, inspect it for test expectations and then call its callback directly to satisfy my test.

I have found an answer to this question, I think. Maybe there's a better answer out there, but I wish the documentation was more clear, or there were better examples in unit tests or better test utilities to do this for you.

Make an Executor, SingleThreadedExecutor, e.g. and add the node to it, but don't spin() it.
From the executor, get_all_callback_groups(); if you're using multiple callback groups, I guess I assume you know how to differentiate which group you want. Otherwise, should just be one element in the list, the default callback group, take that group.
From the callback group, either use find_[subscription,timer,etc.]_ptrs_if(Func func) where func is something like [](const auto& sub){return "foo_topic" = sub->get_topic_name();} or use collect_all_ptrs to get all 'live' pointers to the various things (essentially, I would make all of those functors passed to that method just record all the pointers they receive, or just the pointers of the type you're interested in or whatever.)
Now you have pointers to those various objects and, as far as I've seen so far, you can execute_callback() on a few of them to just trigger their callback method. (TBD on details for how to do that exactly)

But, overall, this pattern allows one to bypass actual message pub/sub during tests, waiting for timers to timeout, etc. You don't have to have several async threads running publishing messages and coordinating behavior, you can just... pretend that you've received a message to the subscriber and continue on. You don't have to sleep while your test does nothing but wait for a timer to timeout, you can just kick it. (though, as a side note, use get_timer_handle() to get the underlying timer implementation, and from that object, you can extract the period so that your unit test can confirm you've set the correct period.)
This only partially works. For Timers and Subscriptions it seems to work okay, pure inputs to the node's function. But it is unclear to me at this time how to monitor node publications or service/client connections.
